# Why is button considered pressed on page refresh and page access?

Tags: php, forms, post, button

I have a simple submit form in `index.php`:

```
<?php
    include('inputs.php');
?>
        <form method="post" action= "/index.php">
            <input class="button" id="restart_device" name="restart_device" type="submit" value="Restart Display" />
        </form>
```

and an action in `inputs.php` file:

```
if(isset($_POST['restart_device'])) {
    shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/restart_device.sh");
}
```

The issue is that this code gets executed on every page refresh or every time I access the page. I don't want this behavior. I want to execute `shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/restart_device.sh");` only on button press, not on page access or page refresh.

I have also tried using `<form method="post" action= "">` but with no success.

Comment: You checked $_POST['restart_device'] value when you refresh page? Because when don't submit form, this param will not set value.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. That is the whole code involving the input form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When refreshing a page loaded with a POST request, most browsers will ask if you want to reissue the request, causing the action to be triggered again. To stop this prompt from appearing append

```
header("Location: /");
die();
```

After the shell_exec. This will redirect the browser to the same page after the action is completed, causing it to switch to GET without any parameters.

Comment: What if I have more than one submit forms on the same page ? Will `header("Location: /"); die();` make the other forms unable to submit values ?

Comment: It will essentially stop the entire execution and reload the page whenever triggered. If the logic for your other forms is correct this shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Great. I have added the lines  inside `if(isset($_POST['restart_device'])) { }` and it works. Thank you.